# Oracle Query Optimization containing many partition clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, window, partition

This is the oracle 11g query I am running.
The table contains a total of 180 Million Records and 400 Columns.
Can you suggest some tuning techniques to make this query faster.
Last time this query without the 'direct' hint option, executed for 2+ hours and went on. I am running now with 'direct' hint option.

```
CREATE /*+ direct */ GLOBAL  TEMPORARY TABLE MAXMINGRP_TEMP
       ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
       AS ( SELECT ORIG_QPL,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORDER_DATE,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,TRIM(PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER)||TRIM(PRODUCT_OPTION_NUMBER) PROD_ID,FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD,SO_DTL_STAT_CD,CONTRA_FG,
    MAX(ORIGINAL_CURRENCY_CODE) OVER(PARTITION BY ORIG_QPL,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORDER_DATE,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,TRIM(PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER)||TRIM(PRODUCT_OPTION_NUMBER),FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD,SO_DTL_STAT_CD,CONTRA_FG) MAX_ORIGINAL_CURRENCY_CODE,
    MIN(ORIGINAL_CURRENCY_CODE) OVER(PARTITION BY ORIG_QPL,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORDER_DATE,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,TRIM(PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER)||TRIM(PRODUCT_OPTION_NUMBER),FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD,SO_DTL_STAT_CD,CONTRA_FG) MIN_ORIGINAL_CURRENCY_CODE,
    MAX(GL_GRP_ACCT_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY ORIG_QPL,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORDER_DATE,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,TRIM(PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER)||TRIM(PRODUCT_OPTION_NUMBER),FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD,SO_DTL_STAT_CD,CONTRA_FG) MAX_GL_GRP_ACCT_ID,
    MIN(GL_GRP_ACCT_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY ORIG_QPL,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORDER_DATE,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,TRIM(PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER)||TRIM(PRODUCT_OPTION_NUMBER),FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD,SO_DTL_STAT_CD,CONTRA_FG) MIN_GL_GRP_ACCT_ID,
    MAX(CUSTOMER_BASE_NUMBER) OVER(PARTITION BY ORIG_QPL,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORDER_DATE,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,TRIM(PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER)||TRIM(PRODUCT_OPTION_NUMBER),FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD,SO_DTL_STAT_CD,CONTRA_FG) MAX_CUSTOMER_BASE_NUMBER,
    MIN(CUSTOMER_BASE_NUMBER) OVER(PARTITION BY ORIG_QPL,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORDER_DATE,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,TRIM(PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER)||TRIM(PRODUCT_OPTION_NUMBER),FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD,SO_DTL_STAT_CD,CONTRA_FG) MIN_CUSTOMER_BASE_NUMBER,
    MAX(REC_EXPLN_CD) OVER(PARTITION BY ORIG_QPL,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORDER_DATE,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,TRIM(PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER)||TRIM(PRODUCT_OPTION_NUMBER),FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD,SO_DTL_STAT_CD,CONTRA_FG) MAX_REC_EXPLN_CD,
    MIN(REC_EXPLN_CD) OVER(PARTITION BY ORIG_QPL,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORDER_DATE,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,TRIM(PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER)||TRIM(PRODUCT_OPTION_NUMBER),FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD,SO_DTL_STAT_CD,CONTRA_FG) MIN_REC_EXPLN_CD,
    MAX(PRFT_CTR_CD) OVER(PARTITION BY ORIG_QPL,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORDER_DATE,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,TRIM(PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER)||TRIM(PRODUCT_OPTION_NUMBER),FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD,SO_DTL_STAT_CD,CONTRA_FG) MAX_PRFT_CTR_CD,
    MIN(PRFT_CTR_CD) OVER(PARTITION BY ORIG_QPL,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORDER_DATE,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,TRIM(PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER)||TRIM(PRODUCT_OPTION_NUMBER),FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD,SO_DTL_STAT_CD,CONTRA_FG) MIN_PRFT_CTR_CD,
    MAX(FUNC_AREA_CD) OVER(PARTITION BY ORIG_QPL,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORDER_DATE,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,TRIM(PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER)||TRIM(PRODUCT_OPTION_NUMBER),FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD,SO_DTL_STAT_CD,CONTRA_FG) MAX_FUNC_AREA_CD,
    MIN(FUNC_AREA_CD) OVER(PARTITION BY ORIG_QPL,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORDER_DATE,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,TRIM(PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER)||TRIM(PRODUCT_OPTION_NUMBER),FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD,SO_DTL_STAT_CD,CONTRA_FG) MIN_FUNC_AREA_CD,
    MAX(ORIG_SOLD_TO_SITE_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY ORIG_QPL,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORDER_DATE,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,TRIM(PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER)||TRIM(PRODUCT_OPTION_NUMBER),FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD,SO_DTL_STAT_CD,CONTRA_FG) MAX_ORIG_SOLD_TO_SITE_ID,
    MIN(ORIG_SOLD_TO_SITE_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY ORIG_QPL,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORDER_DATE,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,TRIM(PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER)||TRIM(PRODUCT_OPTION_NUMBER),FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD,SO_DTL_STAT_CD,CONTRA_FG) MIN_ORIG_SOLD_TO_SITE_ID,
    MAX(SHIP_TO_SITE_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY ORIG_QPL,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORDER_DATE,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,TRIM(PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER)||TRIM(PRODUCT_OPTION_NUMBER),FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD,SO_DTL_STAT_CD,CONTRA_FG) MAX_SHIP_TO_SITE_ID,
    MIN(SHIP_TO_SITE_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY ORIG_QPL,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORDER_DATE,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,TRIM(PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER)||TRIM(PRODUCT_OPTION_NUMBER),FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD,SO_DTL_STAT_CD,CONTRA_FG) MIN_SHIP_TO_SITE_ID,
    MAX(INVOICE_TO_SITE_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY ORIG_QPL,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORDER_DATE,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,TRIM(PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER)||TRIM(PRODUCT_OPTION_NUMBER),FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD,SO_DTL_STAT_CD,CONTRA_FG) MAX_INVOICE_TO_SITE_ID,
    MIN(INVOICE_TO_SITE_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY ORIG_QPL,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORDER_DATE,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,TRIM(PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER)||TRIM(PRODUCT_OPTION_NUMBER),FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD,SO_DTL_STAT_CD,CONTRA_FG) MIN_INVOICE_TO_SITE_ID,
    MAX(END_USER_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY ORIG_QPL,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORDER_DATE,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,TRIM(PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER)||TRIM(PRODUCT_OPTION_NUMBER),FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD,SO_DTL_STAT_CD,CONTRA_FG) MAX_END_USER_ID,
    MIN(END_USER_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY ORIG_QPL,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORDER_DATE,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,TRIM(PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER)||TRIM(PRODUCT_OPTION_NUMBER),FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD,SO_DTL_STAT_CD,CONTRA_FG) MIN_END_USER_ID,
    MAX(ARM_EDIT_CODE) OVER(PARTITION BY ORIG_QPL,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORDER_DATE,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,TRIM(PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER)||TRIM(PRODUCT_OPTION_NUMBER),FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD,SO_DTL_STAT_CD,CONTRA_FG) MAX_ARM_EDIT_CODE,
    MIN(ARM_EDIT_CODE) OVER(PARTITION BY ORIG_QPL,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORDER_DATE,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,TRIM(PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER)||TRIM(PRODUCT_OPTION_NUMBER),FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD,SO_DTL_STAT_CD,CONTRA_FG) MIN_ARM_EDIT_CODE,
    MAX(SAP_ORDER_TYPE) OVER(PARTITION BY ORIG_QPL,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORDER_DATE,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,TRIM(PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER)||TRIM(PRODUCT_OPTION_NUMBER),FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD,SO_DTL_STAT_CD,CONTRA_FG) MAX_SAP_ORDER_TYPE,
    MIN(SAP_ORDER_TYPE) OVER(PARTITION BY ORIG_QPL,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORDER_DATE,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,TRIM(PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER)||TRIM(PRODUCT_OPTION_NUMBER),FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD,SO_DTL_STAT_CD,CONTRA_FG) MIN_SAP_ORDER_TYPE,
    MAX(SO_ADJ_CD) OVER(PARTITION BY ORIG_QPL,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORDER_DATE,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,TRIM(PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER)||TRIM(PRODUCT_OPTION_NUMBER),FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD,SO_DTL_STAT_CD,CONTRA_FG) MAX_SO_ADJ_CD,
    MIN(SO_ADJ_CD) OVER(PARTITION BY ORIG_QPL,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORDER_DATE,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,TRIM(PRODUCT_BASE_NUMBER)||TRIM(PRODUCT_OPTION_NUMBER),FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD,SO_DTL_STAT_CD,CONTRA_FG) MIN_SO_ADJ_CD
    FROM ord_dtl );
```

Comment: the partitioning columns are same for all the window funcitons

Comment: There is no ordering in the window functions, so results will vary if multiple lines. Why not just use standard aggregation (`GROUP BY`)

Comment: @JohnHC  Yes..I should have used GROUP BY (Stupid Me)..Now trying with that..I am sure this time , there will be excellent improvement

Comment: I don't think there is any `/*+ direct */` hint. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: You probably mean /*+ APPEND */, not /*+ direct */.  Other options, resource permitting, would be to employ some parallelism.